# module for finding the asset that who has the most options volume

Tags: python, algorithm, module, finance, yfinance

I would like to know if there is a python module that I can get the ticker of the stock, index or etf who has the highest trading volume for its options.
I tried yfinance for listing the assets who have the most options volume but is quite difficult for doing this.

In the code bellow I try to find the 'spy' stocks for example.

```py
import yfinance as yf

tickers = yf.Tickers('SPY')
all_stocks = tickers.tickers

for i in all_stocks:
  print(i)
```

then, I was going build a function to retrieve the volume of each stock of 'spy', but this seems too time consuming.

By that, I need another module, but this time for listing the assets who have the higher volume of  options

I tried to use yfinance, but I have to iterate through all stocks of a index and then sort by volume